# RoR show elements in two columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, split

how can i split elements of a model into two equally sized pieces so that i can show them in two columns?

```
i have this:

element 1
element 2
element 3
element 4
element 5


and i want this:

element 1    element 4
element 2    element 5
element 3
```

`split()` unfortunately removes the middle element.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Show us some code! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Array#in_groups_of is an core extension and only available in Rails. What it uses though is the each_slice method.

You could use it like this:

```
a = ["element 1", "element 2", "element 3", "element 4", "element 5"]
a.each_slice((a.size/2.0).ceil) { |slice| puts slice } if a.size > 0
```

will give you

```
["element 1", "element 2", "element 3"]
["element 4", "element 5"]
```

Note that you must check that *a.size* is bigger then 0 or you will get an ArgumentError exception due to invalid slice size.

Comment: if it's only available in rails, it's perfectly fine.

Comment: Nice call on checking for the size being > 0. That bit me today, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

as i only need to use this in rails, this worked for me:

```
>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>> a.in_groups_of( (a.size/2.0).ceil, false ) if a.size > 0
=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Array#in_groups_of](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Array/Grouping.html#M001216)

This will slice an array in chunks of your liking.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use jQuery. There are several plugins that can accomplish this for you.

Subsequently, after you have the two chunks, start filling up a div with the first group, once you get to the end, start the second group in a second div. Then use css to position and style the two divs beside one another.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to show these elements?

If it's in a view, you should not be modifying your model; your models should stay independent from your presentation.

If you want to present results on a web page, you must use html and css in your view. Even in your view, you probably won't need to "split" your elements into sub arrays.

See [this page](http://fu2k.org/alex/css/cssjunk/ListColumns.mhtml), for example. If you look at the source code, the lists are allways "one after the other", without splitting into groups. The CSS conditions how the text is positioned.

Comment: the page is a bad example because it doesnt lead to the desired order if you recall the code block in my question. i am trying to put each part of the array into an instance variable that is then passed to the view and displayed. or is there a better way?

Comment: Hi patrick, I don't understand why you say that the order isn't conserved. If you have the array like [1,2,3,4] your html items will be <li>1</li> <li>2</li> <li>3</li> etc. You will only have to pass that variable to the view, and it will render it in two columns using css. I see no need of two variables.