# Using Each_Slice with Rails View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model, Article which I want to show in two columns.  It looks like each_slice will split the array, but I'm not sure how to apply it.  When I try to use `each_slice` in my view, I can't get it to work.

In my controller:

```
@articles = Article.order("title ASC")
```

In my view, I want to replace:

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
```

with this:

```
<% @articles.each_slice((@articles.size/2.0).ceil) { |slice| puts slice } if @articles.size > 0 do |article| %>
```

using the code from this answer:
[RoR show elements in two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798579/ror-show-elements-in-two-columns/1798767#1798767)

I'm trying to make two columns of article titles where the the first half goes in column 1, while the second half goes in column 2 (sorted in alphabetical order by title).  Can someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether you mean you're trying to display a single instance of an article across two visual columns in your output, or display a list of Article instances in two columns. Your code would indicate the latter, but your text indicates the former.

Assuming the latter, you shouldn't be using a table to display non-tabular data, especially if you're going to use two columns for the same data. Instead use an ordered list and the appropriate CSS to handle the display across two columns, which could be handled a variety of ways depending on your needs (inline-block elements with a fixed width and a fixed container width would be one pretty affable method).

If you did need to iterate by n using `each_slice` you would want to check the documentation for `each_slice` so you aren't passing the wrong argument to it like you are here. You appear to be wanting to split the array of articles into two columns, sequentially (i.e. so they appear with 1 and 2 horizontally aligned), so you would just call `@articles.each_slice(2) { |(article_a, article_b)| article_a.name, article_b.name }`.

The linked answer splits the data in a way that your markup isn't equipped to handle, delivering two arrays of unspecified length, divided essentially in half. You would then iterate over each of the resulting lists to display them, probably in separate containing elements.

Comment: Thank you.  Sorry for the confusion, I'm trying to display a list of articles in two columns.  I still am not sure how to apply this.  If I put `@articles.each_slice(2) { |(article_a, article_b)| article_a.name, article_b.name }` in the view, I get `syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
...rticle_a.name, article_b.name } `.  It seems that I have to set the sliced arrays to variables and then iterate them, but I'm lost on how to do this still.

Comment: Meant to wrap those comma delimited articles in square brackets, noting them as an array. Are you familiar with Ruby?

Comment: This is really a CSS question, not a Ruby/Rails question. You don't need `each_slice`, or to split the array. And you definitely don't need a `table`.